# Can I use headphones to hear diagnostic beeps from the motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, bios

I've many times problems with the motherboards so when I disassembly laptops I prefer do disconnect the speakers, and use the headphones but I don't know if some sort of diagnostic beeps could be not heard using headphones instead of speaker in a some models of laptop (where they use different circuits). Is anyone aware of this kind of problem using headphones for diagnostic?

Today I don't hear any beeps with headphones or speakers!

Comment: No;  I am not aware of any motherboard that uses the onboard sound device to output the dianostic beeps.  That is normally done by a mono-speaker handled by the case and/or a mono-speaker connected directly to the motherboard.

Comment: a headphone speaker is probably not much different from a pc speaker... if you were in a situation where you fast wanted to test the mainboard error beeps, you could probably rewire a headphoe instead of a speaker if you didnt have one. the speaker is basically a headphone type speaker, it ca play music.

Answer (score 4):

The error beeps or signals for that matter (sometimes they're led's) use different methods depending on brand, motherboard, chipset, etc. So it will not always work when using headphones, but there should be an onboard speaker that always is used if no cable is plugged in, unless this speaker is missing on the motherboard.

So basically, you should not rely on the headphones alone to hear the error beeps.